# Is there a way to replace a YAML variable in a PowerShell replace script?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, yaml

I am trying to take a variable from a variable group in Azure DevOps, enter it in to a PowerShell script that will change the value.

My variable group looks like:

The variable group name is = variableGroup, The only variable is = name: 'Alex'

dashboardTable.md (Trying to replace the string 'Alex')

`My name is Alex.`

azure-pipelines.yml

```
variables:
- group: variableGroup

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: '(Get-Content ./dashboardTable.md).replace("$(name)", 'Bob') | Set-Content ''./dashboardTable.md'''
```

Is this not actually possible or is my syntax wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to *consistently* escape the `'` characters *embedded* in the overall `'...'` string as `''`:

```yaml
variables:
- group: variableGroup

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: '(Get-Content ./dashboardTable.md).replace(''$(name)'', ''Bob'') | Set-Content ./dashboardTable.md'
```

You can simplify the string by using `"..."` as the outer quoting, in which case no escaping is required for embedded `'`:

```yaml
variables:
- group: variableGroup

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: "(Get-Content ./dashboardTable.md).replace('$(name)', 'Bob') | Set-Content ./dashboardTable.md"
```

However, note that `"..."` strings in YAML interpret `\` as the escape character, so **if a PowerShell command enclosed in `"..."` contains instance of `\`, *they* must be doubled (`\\`)**: